# App-script to pull data from email attachment (text file) to Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Hi I wrote this script to pull data from an email attachment into a Google Sheet and although it seems to work, it stops after writing the data into the range with an exception error that the columns don't match the range. Even though I logged it and it does.

3:16:02 PM  Info    6065.0

3:16:02 PM  Info    33.0

3:16:22 PM  Error
Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 33.

```js
function myFunction() {
  
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Example').getThreads() ,
      message = threads[0].getMessages()[0],
      attachment = message.getAttachments()[0],
      date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yy");

  var data = attachment.getDataAsString().split(/\n/).map(r => r.split(/\t/));
  Logger.log(data);
  
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.clearContents();
  var row1 = data.length;
  var col1 = data[0].length;
  Logger.log(row1);
  Logger.log(col1);

  sheet.getRange(1,1,row1,col1).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: can you give us an simplified example of the text file attached to the email? I have tested a solution with a limited text file without any error.

Comment: @MikeSteelson How do I share some text to you?

Comment: ok, thx, the problem is that I can't get tabs in your file that I downloaded, but lots of spaces, can you confirm from the original, I will try to replace multiple spaces by \t

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  var data = attachment.getDataAsString().replace(/([ ]{2,})/gm, "\t").split(/\n/).map(r => r.split(/\t/));
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.clearContents();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, data[i].length).setValues(new Array(data[i]));
  }
```

Comment: That give me this: Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 10000000 cells.  also i logged the rows and columns of the data and it was 6065.0 and 33.0.

Comment: can you give us an simplified example of the text file attached to the email? I have tested the solution with a limited text file.

Comment: try with this updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Is this any help?

```
function myFunction() {
  
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Example').getThreads() ,
      message = threads[0].getMessages()[0],
      attachment = message.getAttachments()[0],
      date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yy");

  var data = attachment.getDataAsString().split(/\n/).map(r => r.split(/\t/));
  Logger.log(data);
  
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.clearContents();
  var row1 = data.length;
  var col1 = data[0].length;
  Logger.log(row1);
  Logger.log(col1);

  /* ↓↓↓ */
  const hasEqualColumns = data.every(row => row.length === data[0].length)
  if (!hasEqualColumns) {
    data = data.map(row => {
      if (row.length !== data[0].length) {
        return [...row, ...Array(data[0].length-row.length).fill(``)]
      } else { return row }
    })
    sheet.getRange(1,1,row1,col1).setValues(data);
  } else {
    sheet.getRange(1,1,row1,col1).setValues(data);
  }

}
```

I'm going to guess there's a row in the array that is not equal to the range's column width. This snippet will check if there's an inequality of column lengths, and append empty cells to make any 'uneven' rows fit the range.